# Изменение html при уменьшении экрана

Tags: html5

Как сделать чтобы например при переходе в мобильную версию менялась структура html, именно html, а не стили.

Comment: а зачем вам менять структуру? можно сделать, конечно. с помощью js.

Comment: мне для мобильной версии, для удобного использования

Comment: можете простой пример привести если не затруднить,мне принцип понять

Comment: так поменяйте стили. почему нет? вам не нужно менять структуру для перехода на мобилки

Comment: Если вы начинающий, то посмотрите как работают фреймверки, например bootstrap. И тогда поймёте как самому можно будет написать.

Comment: Наверное в вопросе лучше явно уточнить, нужны ли вам ответы основанные на генерации HTML на сервере и если да, то что вы используете - PHP, ASP.NET, может быть какой-нибудь известный фреймворк или CMS.